# Rails find by something other than id for show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm new to rails and I'm working on a site where you can enter yhour judo club and I'm trying to make it so the address is /club/denjudo for example rather than /clubs/2.  On the index page I am able to set it up so you can click on the club and it will take you do  clubs/denjudo but I cannot get it go access the recofd for the correct club, it seems to select a rendom club and show that info.  For the controller I have:

```
def show 
  @club = Club.find_by(params[:club_username])
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set at `routes.rb`

```
 get '/clubs/:club_username', to: 'clubs#show', as: 'club'
```

Then, make sure that `club_username` param is unique at your schema.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I really appreciate your help.  I would rather leanr to do this rather than using a gem when possible.

Answer (score 2):

You want to just specify the attribute you are looking up by.  Based on your example.

```
Club.find_by(username: params[:club_username])
```

Comment: I tried Club.find_by(club_username: params[:club_username]) but it doesn't seem to be getting the club_username from the url which in this case is denjudo

Comment: @StephenScottMoore you need a route like `get 'clubs/:club_username', to: 'clubs#show', as: :club` (In newer versions of rails `resources :clubs, param: :club_username` will handle all of the CRUD routes for you). Given the fact that this is all very new to you, you could just use a library like [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) which won't teach you as much but it will be much easier to set up.